# Axios fetch json data using vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, fetch, axios

nI try to fetch some userdata from a mongodb (json format) using `axios.get` within an `vue.js` application. After this, i want to visualize this data using a iteration through all user-objects within the users array. But my problem is, that every single character is a single object in this array. What i want is, that every single user-json file is one object in this array. If i have three user-objects user.length should be three.
Here the code for the `axios` call:

```
axios
    .get(RL + "/users")
    .then(response => {       
        this.users = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
        console.log("Errors in Users: " + e);
    });
```

And with this snipped i want to iterate through all objects, displaying the username. But `user.name` is always only a single character and not the whole name.

```
<div v-if="users">
    <li v-for="user in users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide example of your response?

Comment: When i use console.log(this.users) it only gives me [object Object]. But when i use console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users)) it gives me the following json-like output for one user: {“payload”:{“forename”:“jon”,“surname”:“doe”,“age”:“28”}}

Comment: It just returns one object with one user, what is the problem then? What happens if you get more users?

Comment: I doubt very much that `console.log(this.users)` produces `[object Object]`.

Comment: @ElDanielo this doesnt change anything of the problem. More users would simply result in more single characters i would iterate over.

Comment: @Phil this is the output i receive. Dunno why...

Comment: Look in your browser's *Network* console for the request to `/users`. What **exactly** does the response look like?

Comment: JSON:
 `JSON 
payload {…}
forename jon
surname doe
age 28
success true ` 
Answer: `{"payload":{"forename":"jon","surname":"doe","age":"28"},"success":true}`

Comment: I think a screenshot would be easier to understand but it looks to me like a) There is only one user being returned, b) the user is stored in `response.data.payload`, and c) there is definitely no `name` property

Comment: Apparently your response, or the way you handle it is the cause of the issue. It'd be helpful to provide a screenshot of the request data from the networks tab in Developer Tools, as well as a `console.log` of `response.data`

Comment: can you post how's your backend code look like?. It seems you want to return all users but only one shows. Maybe you only have one user in db or your backend code return only one. Try this in your success response for (const [index, value] of response.data.entries()) {
        console.log(index)
       console.log(value)
} supposing your returning response.data contains the object and see what it look like

Comment: @OverCoder the console.log of response.data only shows me [object Object] as mentioned above. A simple console.log(typeof response.data) gives a object as result

Answer (score 0):

Without any plugin.

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

```
// YOUR DATA HERE
data: {
    filterResult: [] // THIS IS YOUR JSON FILE
},

// READY FUNCTION HERE
created: function() {
    this.filterResult = this.dataResult();
},

// YOU FUNCTION HERE
methods: {
    // CALLING API
    dataResult: function() {
        $.getJSON('/api/feature/stores/list', function(json) {
            app.results = json;
            app.filterResult = json;
        });
    },
}
```

});